# Finding a function based on the Taylor Expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion

I am given the Taylor Expansion of a function *h(x)*.

$$h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n = x + 2x^2 + 3x^3+\cdots$$

Using the definition of a Taylor Series, I get that:
$h(0) = 0$, $h'(0) = 1$, $h''(0) = 4$, and $h'''(x) = 18.$
I am not really sure where to go from here. This seems somewhat similar to the Taylor Series for $x/(1-x)$, but it isn't quite there.

Comment: `somewhat similar to the Taylor Series for x/(1−x)` Not a bad way to think at it. How about you try to differentiate that, then multiply by $x$ again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall that the geometric series, when it converges, is equal to
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
Now take this formula and differentiate both sides:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
then multiply both sides by $x$:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
and so you have
$$\color{green}{h(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}}$$
Using this neat trick, can you find a formula for
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2x^n=\text{?}$$

Answer (score 2):

For $|x|<1$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
h(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^{n} \\
&= x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n x^{n-1} \\
&= x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} \right) \\
&= x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right) \\
&= \frac{x}{(1-x)^{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$